# C# Class Structure to Ensure Certain Filters Are Always Applied

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-5

So I'm currently working on a project with a team, and my team and I have come across a certain design scenario that we are trying to come up with a solution for.

**Background Info of Current Project Implementation:**

This problem involves three main projects in our solution: Repository, Models, and Services project. In case it isn't obvious, the purpose of each project is as follows. The **Models** project contains models of all the data we store in our database. The **Repository** project has one main database access class that uses generics to interact with different tables depending on the model passed in. Lastly the **Services** project contains classes that interface data between the front-end and repository, and in general each service class maps 1-to-1 to a model class. As one would expect, the build dependencies are: Repository relies on Models, and Services relies on both projects.

**The Issue:**

The current issue we are encountering is that we need a way to ensure that if a developer attempts to query or interact with a specific type of object (Call it ModelA), then we want to ensure that a specific set of filters is always included by default (and these filters are partially based on if a particular user has permissions to view certain objects in a list). A developer should be able to override this filter.

What we want to avoid doing is having an if clause in the repository classes that says "if you're updating this model type, add these filters".

**Solutions we have thought of / considered:**

One solution we are currently considering is having a function in ServiceA (the service corresponding to ModelA) that appends these filters to a given query, and then to make it so that if anyone requests for the db context of a model, they must pass in a function that manipulates filtering in some fashion (in other words, if they want to interact with ModelA, they would pass in the filter function from ServiceA). The issue with this solution is that a developer needs to always be aware that if they ever interact with ModelA, they must pass in the function from ServiceA. Also, because we don't want every model to enforce certain filter options, we would likely want this to be an optional parameter, which might then cause issues where developers simply forget to include this function when interacting with ModelA.

Another solution we considered is to have an attribute (let's call it DefaultFilterAttribute) on ModelA that stores a class type that should implement a particular interface (called IFilterProvider). ServiceA would implement this interface, and ModelA's attribute would be given ServiceA as a type. Then the repository methods can check if the entity passed in has a DefaultFilterAttribute on it, and then simply call the method implemented by the class attached to the attribute. Unfortunately, as some of you might have noticed, the way our project dependencies are currently set up, we can't really implement a solution like this.

So I'm wondering if there is a clean solution to this problem, or if potentially we are thinking about the problem and/or design pattern incorrectly, and should be taking a completely different approach.

Comment: Have looked at an aspect-oriented-programming solution like PostSharp?

Comment: @KevinRaffay I haven't heard of this before, however it seems like this solution involves using a different compiler. I would prefer to simply try to find a solution with the context of the C# language without any additional interfacing. Although PostSharp seems very interesting, I ask the other developers I work with to install, learn and use this tool.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making this unnecessarily complex. What you're describing is pretty much the entire purpose of a service layer. Presumably, you'd have something like `GetModelAList` (that's actually a pretty bad method for a service, but just for illustration). The logic of applying certain filters automatically, then, is encapsulated in that method. The application doesn't know or care *how* that data is retrieved; it just knows if it wants a list of `ModelA` instances, it calls that method.

If you then want a way to not apply those filters, you can provide another method such as `GetModelAListUnfiltered`, or pass a boolean or something in to the original method that determines whether filters are automatically applied. Really you can handle this however you want, but the point is that it's all encapsulated in your service.

Lastly, you haven't specified exactly what your repository is doing, but a repository should be *extremely* simple, really just returning sets of all objects. Logic like what you're talking about belongs in a service layer. However, even that only applies if you're doing direct database access using something like Dapper or ADO.NET. If you're using a full-fledged ORM like Entity Framework, throw away your repository layer entirely. Yes, you heard me correctly: throw it away completely. A repository wrapped around an ORM is a useless abstraction, only serving to add more code that needs to be maintained  and tested for no good reason whatsoever. The benefits some level of abstraction gives you is already provided by the service layer.

Comment: Yeah, that's how I viewed the service as well. I noticed however that a lot of code has been added where ModelA data is accessed in services other than ServiceA. But from your response I guess rather than allowing people to do that, I should just rewrite all the code so that ModelA data is only changed in ServiceA. 

Also about the Repository project, we seem to use several different databases / tools to interact with them, so the classes in there are meant to make access to all databases more consistent, from what I understand.

Comment: @ShajeshJ That too is a job for the service layer. A repository should just be an abstraction of raw SQL. Anything else is abuse.